How to use SKIP properly with special characters?
I have this regex expression link
(\b(?:(?:highp|lowp|mediump|return|\?|\=)(?:\s+\w+)*\s+(float|(?:i|b)?vec[2-4]|mat[2-4](?:x[2-4])?))(*SKIP)(?!)|(?=\b(float|(?:i|b)?vec[2-4]|mat[2-4](?:x[2-4])?)))

It should match float keywords, where there are no question mark or assignment operator or return keyword before them with the use of *SKIP. As well as I would like to avoid cases, where there is a precision modifier before them.
Unfortunately I cannot make the regex SKIP work with the question mark and the assignment operator.
I would like to capture the first two lines only:
float x;          // this case matches in the right way
const float x;    // this case matches in the right way
precision highp float;  //this case doesn't match, it is good
return float x;    // this case doesn't match, it is good
? float x;    // this case matches, but it shouldn't 
= float x;    // this case matches, but it shouldn't 


UPDATE 1:
It seems that if I delete the \b from the beginning it is better but still if I write =float(1.0f) or ?float(1.0f) then it is still a match. updated regex

Simply because there is no word char before the question mark. Only use a word boundary when there must be one. And do not use (?:i|b)?, use [ib]?

And if you do not want to match =float(1.0f) and ?float(1.0f), just make \s+ optional, \s*. See https://regex101.com/r/46o3vf/2
